# How to extract whole table tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div class="test">
<table> 
  <tr valign="center"> 
    <td><a href="url" target="_blank"></a></td> 
    <td>abc </td> 
    <td>pqr</td> 
    <td>xyz</td> 
 </tr>
</table>
```

HTML text

I have this as string in javascript. I would like to extract the whole of  table tag.

```
 <table> 
  <tr valign="center"> 
    <td><a href="url" target="_blank"></a></td> 
    <td>abc </td> 
    <td>pqr</td> 
    <td>xyz</td> 
  </tr> 
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var tableString = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].innerHTML;
```

With jQuery you could do something like

```
var tableString = $('div.test table').html();
```

Comment: I was just about to write this myself, figured it out, great thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want...

`$('.test table')` gives you the table.

`$('.test table').html()` the html code.

`$('.test').html('')` removes it from the page.

Answer (score 0):

If by "the whole table tag" you mean the HTML that includes the start and end TABLE tags, then you can do something like:

```
var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];

if (table) {

  // If outerHTML property available, use it
  if (typeof table.outerHTML == 'string') {
    return table.outerHTML;

  // Otherwise, emualte it
  } else {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.appendChild(table.cloneNode(true));
    return div.innerHTML;
  }
}
```